# Do not display the gif loader When canceling the registration of the form with e.preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and I have an image in it that shows the user when the form is submitted, waiting for the operation to be completed.
I have no problem with submit operation.

When the form registration is canceled with `e.preventDefault()`, how can I not display the gif loader so that the user can control his inputs?

The problem is that when the submitting is canceled, the gif loader is still displayed

`AddEdit` form:

```
<div id="pageloader" style="display:none">
    <img src="~/Content/Images/loader.gif" alt="Loading..."/>
</div>
    
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#AddEditForm").on("submit", function (e) {
            $("#pageloader").fadeIn();
        });//submit
    });
    

    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").submit(function (e) {
            if (!validData()) {                        
                e.preventDefault();                         
                return false;
            }
            return true;                    
        });
    });
    
</script>
    
    
<style>
    #pageloader {
        background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.7 );
        display: none;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
    
    #pageloader img {
        left: 60%;
        margin-left: -32px;
        margin-top: -32px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40%;
    }
</style>
```

I want to write a general function or event that whenever any form registration is canceled, the gif is not displayed or its display is stopped.

Can I do that?

Comment: `$("#pageloader").fadeOut();` where you do `e.preventDefault();` I would guess - it's hard, since your code indentation is bet described as *random*

Comment: @Bravo: Code indentation corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$("#pageloader").fadeOut();` or `$("#pageloader").hide();` when your data is not valid like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        if (!validData()) {
            $("#pageloader").fadeOut();
            //or $("#pageloader").hide();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

Here is working sdample:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#AddEditForm").on("submit", function (e) {
        $("#pageloader").fadeIn();
    });//submit
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        if (!validData()) {
            $("#pageloader").fadeOut();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
});


function validData() {
      return false;
}
```

```css
 #pageloader {
            background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.7 );
            display: none;
            height: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 9999;
        }

            #pageloader img {
                left: 60%;
                margin-left: -32px;
                margin-top: -32px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 40%;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="pageloader" style="display:none">
    <img src="loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>

<form id="AddEditForm">
     <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: @user3274226 I updated my answer to create a working snippet. As you can see everything works fine.

Comment: thanks a lot.
Is it possible to write general code for all forms when the submission of each form was canceled $("# pageloader"). FadeOut (); To run?
like  $(document)
            .ajaxStart(function () {
                $("# pageloader").show();
            }) for ajax...

Comment: @user3274226 You need to write base code (general code) for submit button, and also for validate methods. in your base submit function you can do like my answer

Comment: @user3274226 It is good idea when someone help you, vote them :)

Comment: do You can help to write base code (general code) for submit button?

Comment: @user3274226 It is good Idea to use Object Oriented. you can use (typescript class or something else) then you can use some base class and interface with base methods (base validation methods). I highly recommended first determine with external library want to use such as Angular, React, pure typescript .... then you can design your architecture of code